# NSInternalInconsistencyException reason: couldn't load nib into bundle

Tags: ios6, runtime-error, xib

I am working on how to use the core data framework, but when I run my apps, it shows an error which is-

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "myCoreDataViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1fa3012 0x13e0e7e 0x1fa2deb 0xf58c8 0xf5dc8 0xf5ff8 0xf6232 0x453d5 0x4576f 0x45905 0x4e917 0x2095 0x12157 0x12747 0x1394b 0x24cb5 0x25beb 0x17698 0x1efedf9 0x1efead0 0x1f18bf5 0x1f18962 0x1f49bb6 0x1f48f44 0x1f48e1b 0x1317a 0x14ffc 0x1d8d 0x1cb5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I searched on it a lot but couldn't find any solutions. Please help.

Note:

- My .xib file is already in copy bundle resources in build phases.
- The name is also correct.
- I have removed it and added it again, but no benefit.
- My .xib file is linked with target in target membership.

I have already tried the above solutions, so please don't tell about them again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, go to /Users/(user name)/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications and delete the folder that contains your app.  Delete all the folders if you are running on different builds (5.1, 6.0, 7.0, etc..).

Next, delete the application from the simulator/iOS device and rebuilding the app (click and hold on the app and push the x key to remove it). Then rebuild the app.